# What is this spell?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, voldemort

Is Voldemort casting Avada Kedavra in this scene in *Deathly Hallows II*? If not what spell then?

[image: --]

There are only [a few things that can block Avada Kedavra](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/30805/19561): Love magic - Priori incantem - Physical objects.

This can't be Avada Kedavra then, because Harry is indeed deflecting it with something that looks like Protego.  So what spell is Voldemort using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Avada Kedavra considered unblockable?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30805/why-is-avada-kedavra-considered-unblockable)

Comment: Nope my question is more about which spell voldemort is casting and if so how can harry deflect it using "protego" probably. Its not about the blocking.

Comment: if it *is* avada kedavra, it becomes a dupe as the other question explains how it's deflected.

Comment: seeing as the "why is harry able to deflect avada kevadra" portion is already covered, you should probably just focus this question entirely on identifying the spell.

Comment: A spell of Someone Making The Film Being High On Something And Making Stuff Up. More seriously, JKR explicitly said she's largely happy with any changes made from books to movies, so us plebs shouldn't complain about nonsensical film details.

Comment: Even more seriously, I don't recall any of the supporting DVDs mentioning this. But @Slytherincess may have something nuanced in that uber-book of hers about how the films were made.

Comment: Tagging with "movie" as the question is film canon specific

Comment: Can you please edit the text of the question to describe where that image is from?  Eg. what movie and which part of that movie?

Comment: ***Avada Plothala!!*** - in all seriousness, Voldemort uses AK 95% of the times so this is most likely it.

Comment: Just a note: [Priori Incantatem](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Priori_Incantatem) is not a spell, it is an effect produced when two wands that share the same cores are forced into combat. The spell that Harry uses that produces this effect is Expelliarmus.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20049/why-was-harry-casting-shield-charms-against-voldemort-in-the-battle-of-hogwarts

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22244/how-was-harry-able-to-block-a-killing-curse-conjured-by-a-death-eater-that-was-a

Comment: At what stage of the film is this? If after the forest, would Harry not be immune to Voldemort's powers (like those around him are due to Harry's sacrifice)?

Comment: @JonStory Its after the forest,

Comment: So does someone already know how harry managed to block / reflect / delete the attacks from Voldi

Comment: Roel, nobody knows for sure but there are four potential reasons - 1. it wasn't Avada Kedavra (therefore was blockable). 2. Because the elder wand wouldn't kill its true owner. 3. Because Harry sacrificed himself to protect everyone (including himself) from Voldemort or 4) we misinterpreted the 'Avada Kedavra can't be stopped' thing, and it actually means 'you're killed instantly and can't be revived' not 'it can't be blocked in any way'

Answer (score 9):

I see from the comments that we have two issues:

- What spell is Voldemort using, and
- if it is Avada Kedavra, how can Harry block it?

---

Clearly I am writing out of pure speculation:

I feel that the spell used is most definitely Avada Kedavra, mainly because of the signature green flash, the fact that Voldemort uses it almost all the time, and also given the situation: hell broke loose and everyone has chosen to fight - Voldemort got no reason to subjugate/harm professors or students that oppose him. He needs to dispose of them. Oh and also the fact that this is a movie adaptation: I'm sure the director would realize that *Voldemort using a green spell that is NOT Avada Kedavra* would be very confusing to the audience.

Said that, it boils down to the next question: how can Harry block this supposed Avada Kedavra? The comments insist that [Why is Avada Kedavra considered unblockable?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30805/why-is-avada-kedavra-considered-unblockable) shows how is this possible, but the accepted answer does not apply to this context: Harry is not using a physical object, nor is Priori Incantatem possible in this scene and he is definitely not under Lily's protection either. He is obviously using a spell.

My guess is that it is the same reason why Harry's Expelliarmus surpassed Voldemort's Avada Kedavra in the final showdown: Voldemort's wand is not his. The Elder Wand's true master is Harry and hence it will refuse to kill Harry, who happens to be in the middle of the attack. Avada Kedravra was powerless against Expelliarmus in the final scene, and by that fact I conclude the Avada Kedavra used in OP's picture was also powerless against whatever defensive spell Harry used: the Elder Wand will not kill its true master.

There is an obvious flaw with the above speculation. Voldemort should realize that something is *wrong*. He used Avada Kedavra and Harry blocked it! Why would he continue fighting? This may very well prove that the above conclusions are wrong, **or** the solution is something much simpler: Voldemort is proud and arrogant and there is no way he is going to flee when the whole crowd is watching him and Harry circle each other to kill.

That's my two cents.

Comment: THE DARK LORD HAS RETURNED!

Comment: I'd actually just updated my answer to indicate that it couldn't be blocked by spells (since no one ever blocks it with a shield in the books) and here's an on-screen example of it blocked by a shield!  I just can't win ;-)

Comment: Ur saying that the Elder Wand's true master is Harry and hence it will refuse to kill Harry,
But he killed harry in the forbidden forest with the elder wand :)

Comment: @Roel He never truly dies. Besides, Harry *allowed* being shot. Certainly the wording shouldn't have been "it won't kill Harry", but rather "it won't *oppose* Harry".

Comment: @Voldemort mmh, definitly gotta search that part out. This question is good for the other question where theyre making a discussion about the blocking. Which harry indeed does here by using expelliarmus

Comment: @Roel I think he used *Protego* in this particular scene according to the book.

Comment: @HarryJohnston really? I remember expelliarmus was used in the final battle but, when Voldemort sets off to kill Molly I think Harry used something else. Because it's kinda weird to use Expelliarmus to protect someone lol.

Comment: @Voldemort: oh, I misunderstood.  Yes, that was Protego. In that scene Voldemort didn't get around to casting a spell at Molly at all, or at least the book doesn't mention one.  He just pointed his wand at her.

Comment: (If he had cast Avada Kedavra at her, though, the Protego spell would probably have protected her, because it was reinforced by Harry's earlier sacrifice of himself.)

Comment: @roel Harry doesn't die from the Elder Wand in the forest... That's kind of, you know, the **entire point of the ending of the story**